# Nest controllers best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my app I have 2 classes Phone, Address. Both related to tables in my DB (using entity framework), and have the corresponding controllers with the CRUD methods and corresponding views

```
public class Phone
{
    [Key]
    public int PhoneID { get; set; }
    public PHONETYPE PhoneType { get; set; }}//i.e: mobile, private, office, fax
    public string OriginalNumber{ get; set; }
    public string IndexedNumber{ get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int ADDRESSTYPE { get; set; } //enum i.e.: billing, delivery etc
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public int PostCodeID { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am about to create 2 other classes and it’s corresponding controllers, views and tables, which will be something as the following:

```
public class Student
{
    String name,
    String mainSubject;
    int gender;
    ……
    List<int> phoneID;
    List<int> addressID;
    ….
}

public class School
{
    String name,
    Bool isGoverment
    …..
    List<int> PhoneID;
    List<int> AddressID;
    ….
}
```

My Question:
I want to create the Student and School controllers correctly. As you see each of them have Address and Phone.

There may be more than 1 phone or address per school\student: once the end user entering a school\student details he will have the option to “Add another Address” \ “Add another Phone”

What is the way to code the Student \ School controllers, so they will use the controllers I already have for Phone and Address? I read about ChildAction, Routing Attributes. Do I need to use any of those to make it happen ? or what will you do ?

Comment: You don't need any of that, specially if you are using Entity Framework. What you should do is have a `StudentViewModel` that has a `List<PhoneViewModel>` and a `List<AddressViewModel>`. Then, you would use Partial Views for the creation of the phones and addresses *inside* the create Student view. You would then, on the `POST CreateStudent` action, convert those ViewModels into the appropriate classes for Entity Framework

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I was thinking about this, but I am unsure if I got it right. I use the Repository Pattern, and the Phone and Address have corosponding Repositories and tables.. The PhoneController has the PhoneRepository as a private member. I am not sure what should be included in the <PhoneViewModel>?

Comment: A ViewModel is just a class that you create that has the properties and validations you need for a particular action. For example, a CreateViewModel wouldn't have an Id property (as an item does not exist, the client cannot know it)  but an EditViewModel would have a required Id property

Comment: wanted to say THANK YOU, I started implementing this and I think I am in the right way. Thanks for your tips :-)